# How to remove selected input object from form data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have HTML file as:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="icons-tab-steps wizard-circle" action="{{url('/shelter/intake')}}">

    <input type="file" name="data[person][person_identification1]" 
    id="preview_preson_1_stray">
    <a href="#" onclick="deleteSelection('1','stray')">
        <span class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </a>

</form>
```

When I click on delete then object should gets removed from **data[person][person_identification1]**. How to do this? Please help in this.

Comment: can you please provide your code that shows deleteSelection() function

Comment: I havn't added anything in deleteSelection() function, Don't know how to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Remove From UI**

In Delete function you will get 1,stray & id will be create separately the create id in javascript & remove

```
var no = 1;
var stmt = stray;

$("#preview_preson"+_no_stmt).remove()
```

Comment: Not from UI, I want to delete from data that will gets submitted i.e from data[person][person_identification1]

Comment: Okay, I'll try this.

Comment: Wow works great. Thank you. But How to implement this if input type file have mulitple selection?

Comment: You have to use different ids for each input & get selected checkbox list & remove it